# Submitting Form Data in IE and Edge

Tags: html, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I am doing a little website, but I have a problem with my forms — IE and MS Edge can't send information from my forms.

Here is my form (login / register, I am calling them through JavaScript):

```html
<div class="forms">
    <button id="login"> Již mám účet </button>
    <button id="registration"> Chci začít naplno! </button>
    <form id="login_form" method="POST" action="templates/script/login.php">
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Váš email" pattern=".{0}|.{5,64}" required title="Zadejte prosím 5 až 64 symbolů" />
        <br />
        <input id="pswd" type="password" name="pswd" placeholder="Vaše heslo" pattern=".{0}|.{5,32}" required title="Zadejte prosím 5 až 32 symbolů"/>
        <br />
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Přihlásit se" />
        <br /><br />
        <a id="forgotten_pswd" href="recovery.php" title="Zapomněl jsem heslo ;("> Zapomněl jsem svoje heslo </a>
    </form>
    <form id="registration_form" method="POST" action="templates/script/registration.php">
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Váš email" pattern=".{0}|.{5,64}" required title="Zadejte prosím 5 až 64 symbolů" />
        <br />
        <input id="nick" type="text" name="nick" placeholder="Vaše jméno" pattern=".{0}|.{5,32}" required title="Zadejte prosím 5 až 32 symbolů" />
        <br />
        <input id="pswd" type="password" name="pswd" placeholder="Vaše heslo" pattern=".{0}|.{5,32}" required title="Zadejte prosím 5 až 32 symbolů" /> 
        <br />
        <input id="re_pswd" type="password" name="re_pswd" placeholder="Znovu heslo" pattern=".{0}|.{5,32}" required title="Zadejte prosím 5 až 32 symbolů" />
        <br />
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Zaregistrovat se" />
        <br /> <br />
    </form>
</div>
```

Now what's going on. Chrome, Safari, Mozilla, Opera send information (from FORMs), but IE and Edge don't. They just show an error (from pattern -> Not enough symbols in input).

Here is the website; you can see it with your own eyes:
http://kocvara.googleplay.cz/index.php

Help me please, thank you!

Comment: You mentioned using JavaScript to submit the data; please also share that code.

Comment: I also have users reporting problems with "Edge". Submitted content gets "cut", so there is obviously a problem with this new browser. I am using SCEditor as wysiwyg frontend. Trying to collect more data on this editor-related problem here: https://github.com/samclarke/SCEditor/issues/501